# Permission - SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list

How can I manage the permission for a resolver group per country?

I created a query management tool using a SharePoint list. So users can input all issues in this tool.

Let's say, I am a member of the resolver group for all items under Philippines. How can I only see the items created by users under Philippines?
The goal is to not have visibility of issues for other countries. 
I should also have the capability to update items under Ph (change of status)

Answer (score 2):

When a query is inserted into your Query Management SharePoint list, at that time break the item level permission of that query and remove the unnecessary groups/users access for that item. Only assign access to proper groups/users and the appropriate Resolver group based on the country of the query with the appropriate permission level (e.g. Contribute or Edit). With having proper accessibility (e.g. Contribute or Edit) on the query item, a member of the Resolver group can update the query details like the 'Status'.

You can achieve this by using an Event Receiver or a SharePoint Designer Workflow.

Comment: How can I use the designer? Do you have sample workflow which i can use?